# Does Azure Push Notification Hub supports iOS PushKit VoIP push notifications?

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-notificationhub, pushkit

I found a few posts related Azure notification hub support on PushKit VoIP notifications:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/afda14fe-1218-4ca1-a1ee-205ccd241d1a/support-for-apple-voip-pushkit-push-notifications?forum=notificationhubs

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/39b4e1cd-842f-4562-bab5-119d5f6175cd/send-ios-voip-pushes?forum=notificationhubs

[Does GCM works with iOS PushKit framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36627984/does-gcm-works-with-ios-pushkit-framework)

There's no official confirmation of the support, I did try myself by using same APN HTTP/2 configuration on my notification hub which you can use for either APN Notifications or PushKit VoIP Notifications but always got invalid token on registration to notification hub.

Have anyone make this work with Azure notification hubs? Is there support for this or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be supported if you use Authentication Mode **Certificate** with a VoIP Services Certificate but not if you use Authentication Mode **Token** with Token-based (HTTP/2) Authentication for APNS.

So to get this working use a VoIP Services Certificate and on Apple Notification Hub Configuration set Authentication Mode **Certificate** with this VoIP certificate.

Comment: Hi, I'm using VOIP notifications in my app and Azure notification hub is used on the server side to trigger the notifications. When hub is kept on Sandbox mode it works fine. But when I set the hub to production mode, notifications are not being received. Can you please help me with it ?

Answer (score 1):

It started to work, but you have to:

- use Token Authentication Mode with HTTP/2
- add .voip suffix to Bundle Id
- specify `apns-push-type` to `voip` when sending notification. (Added because of iOS13)

  ```
      var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      headers.Add("apns-push-type", "voip");
      var notification = new TemplateNotification(parameters);
      notification.Headers = headers;
      await hub.SendNotificationAsync(notification);
  ```

Comment: Do i need to add .voip for non Azure stuff as well to my bundle id? Id so where should i add it? When creating the cert on apple developer or in the app config locally?

Comment: When you are calling Apple server API to send voip push, I think only at that time

Answer (score 0):

I test with Certification mode and VoIP Certificate, but PushKit delegation method which is

> pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry,
>   didReceiveIncomingPushWith....

was not trigged.

This method was trigged:

> application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification